# Model inference using batch

Tags: pytorch, huggingface

I am trying to get an inference of an image using the Pix2struct vision transformer model. Currently, I am generating one inference at a time and the code I am using is in below.

```py
processor = Pix2StructProcessor.from_pretrained(
    "google/deplot", is_vqa=True
)
model = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(
    "google/deplot", is_vqa=True
).to(device)

with open('./data/test_imgs/test.png', "rb") as f:
    image = Image.open(f).convert("RGB")

    inputs = processor(
        images=image,
        text="Generate underlying data table of the figure below:",
        return_tensors="pt",
    ).to(device)
    predictions = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=512)
    deplot_result = processor.decode(
            predictions[0], skip_special_tokens=True
    )
    
    print(deplot_result)
```

However, the inference time for this method is ~45 secs/image, which is not viable for our project. Is there a way to convert this code into using batches so that I can generate multiple predictions at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote and tested the following code and it works. The batch consists of two images, you should be able to generalize it and iterate over the entire dataset. I suggest implementing a pythorch dataset, but I don't know if this is possible in your case.

If you want to test the code, remember to change the names of the images in the batch.

```
from PIL import Image
import torch
from transformers import Pix2StructProcessor, Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')

# Initialize the processor and model
processor = Pix2StructProcessor.from_pretrained("google/deplot", is_vqa=True)
model = Pix2StructForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("google/deplot", is_vqa=True).to(device)

# load images in a list
image_file_paths = ['./data/cat.jpg', './data/dog.jpg']
images = [Image.open(f).convert("RGB") for f in image_file_paths]

# Tokenize and prepare the inputs as a batch
inputs = processor(
    images=images,
    text=["Generate underlying data table of the figure below:"] * len(image_file_paths),  # Use the same text for all images
    return_tensors="pt",
).to(device)

# Generate predictions for the batch and decode them
predictions = model.generate(**inputs)
for i, prediction in enumerate(predictions):
    deplot_result = processor.decode(prediction, skip_special_tokens=True)
    print(f"Result for image {i+1}: {deplot_result}")
```

I tested on this to image: [img_1](https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/fit-in/900x510/https://www.forbes.com/advisor/ca/wp-content/uploads/2023/09/great_dane.jpeg.jpg) and [img_2](https://static01.nyt.com/images/2021/09/14/science/07CAT-STRIPES/07CAT-STRIPES-mediumSquareAt3X-v2.jpg) and I got the following outputs:

```
Result for image 1: TITLE |  <0x0A>  | Frequency<0x0A>(MHz) <0x0A> Unnamed: 1
Result for image 2: Entity | Value <0x0A> rv | 4 <0x0A> t | 2 <0x0A>
```